# Does Cppcheck has a gui for ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: gui, c++, memory-leak

I want to use Cppcheck for my C++ based program.

If yes, how do I install it? I can't seem to find any instruction for that anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to build it from source for 14.04. There are pre-built packages for latest ubuntu versions though [Link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cppcheck-gui)

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the GUI on 14.04 is currently not working (no idea if it is fixable) - see https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/pull/3596#issuecomment-987938175.

On 16.04 you need to use the `qmake` build since CMake won't work - see https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/pull/3596#issuecomment-987967027.

Starting with 18.04 the GUI build works and is checked by our CI. It is also available via the `cppcheck-gui` package so you no longer need to compile it from source.